# phonegap 3.3 - Softkeboard (ios) issue when opening the camera

Tags: cordova-3

After using the camera,  the softkeyboard becomes a complete mess, and unusable. - IOS only -

it happens on v3.3, but because of the following bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5712  iv'e upgraded to 3.5-dev.
And it still happening.

Repeat:

1. open the softkeyboard by clicking on any input form
2. open the camera, i.e. integrate the camera plugin, create a button in the UI and click it.
3. open the softkeyboard by clicking on any input form

result: keyborad UI unusable

ENV - IOS7, JQM 1.3.2, JQ 1.8.2, Cordova 3.3

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer but I found that if you pop up an alert msg after the camera is closed than the keyboard displays with no problems.